# How to add new observation to already created dataset in SAS?

Tags: sas

How to add new observation to already created dataset in SAS ? For example, if I have dataset 'dataX' with variable 'x' and 'y' and I want to add new observation which is multiplication by two of the 
of the observation number n, how can I do it ?

dataX :
x y
1 1
1 21
2 3

I want to create :

dataX :
x y
1 1
1 21
2 3
10 210

where observation number four is multiplication by ten of observation number two.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you are trying to do, could you provide an example of what the before and after datasets will look like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

```
data dataX;
   input x y;
   datalines;
1 1
1 21
2 3
run;

/* Create a new observation into temp data set */
data _addRec;
  set dataX(firstobs=2); /* Get observation 2 */
   x = x * 10;  /* Multiply each by 10 */
   y = y * 10;
   output;      /* Output new observation */
   stop;
run;

/* Add new obs to original data set */
proc append base=dataX data=_addRec;
run;

/* Delete the temp data set (to be safe) */
proc delete data=_addRec;
run;
```

Comment: I realized that I need solution which will work when placed inside do-loop, could you show me solution in this case ?

Comment: What kind of "do loop"?  It might be best for you to ask another question.  Give a clear description and I'm sure you'll get an answer.  You can refer back to this one, but only if it's relevant to your new question.

Answer (score 6):

```
data X;
input x y;
datalines;
1 1
1 21
2 3 
;
run;



data X ;
set X end=eof;
if eof then do;
output;
x=10 ;y=210;
end;
output;
run;
```

Comment: REVIEW of low quality post: Please add some description for the proposed solution. This answer in it's current form is likely to be deleted for moderation reasons.

Answer (score 4):

```
data a ;
 do kk=1 to 5 ;
    output ;
 end ;
run;

data a2 ;
    kk=999 ;
    output ;
run;

data a; set a a2 ;run ;

proc print data=a ;run ;
```

Result:
 The SAS System                               1

```
                              OBS     kk

                               1       1
                               2       2
                               3       3
                               4       4
                               5       5
                               6     999
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use macro to obtain your desired result :

1. Write a macro which will read first `DataSet` and when `_n_=2` it will multiply x and y with 10.
2. After that create another `DataSet` which will hold only your muliplied value let say `x'=10x` and `y'=10y`.
3. Pass both `DataSet` in another macro which will set the original datset and newly created dataset.

Logic is you have to create another dataset with value `10x` and `10y` and after that set wih previous dataset.

I hope this will help !

Comment: how to make the same using 4GL ?

Comment: I think macros should be avoided unless there's a reason - they often add unnecessary complexity.  In this case the problem can solved just with a regular datastep.